# How change only specific child styles property in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stylesheet

Code:

```
<View style={mainContainerStyle}>
    <View style={style1}>
      {View1}
    </View>
    <View style={style2}>
      {View2}
    </View>
    <View style={style3}>
      {View3}
    </View>
    <View style={style4}>
      {View4}
    </View>
</View>
```

In this case, I want to check: style1, style2, style3, style 4. These are child styling properties.

If I find any style `{ flexDirection: 'row' }`, I should make it `'row-reverse'`. How to achieve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a function to do that specific logic

```
function format(style) {
  if (style.flexDirection === 'row') {
    return Object.assign({}, style, { flexDirection: 'row-reverse' });
  }
  return style;
}
```

and wrap it up:

```
<View style={mainContainerStyle}>
    <View style={format(style1)}>
      {View1}
    </View>
    <View style={format(style2)}>
      {View2}
    </View>
    <View style={format(style3)}>
      {View3}
    </View>
    <View style={format(style4)}>
      {View4}
    </View>
</View>
```